# Set branch postback url parameter with track url parameter

Tags: branch

I'm trying to add just one parameter to my postback url to a custom partner. What I need is to pass a Click Id that advertiser will put into link. For example hi'll make traffic to this link - cq8y2.app.link/?click_id=777 how could i map that click_id parameter to postback url?

Answer (score 0):

You should use a macro to extract the click_id value. Append to the postback URL as a GET-parameter the following:

```
?clickid=${ (last_attributed_touch_data.~click_id)! }
```